# mocha mongoose error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mocha.js

I get the following error in my mocha tests when mongoose tries to connect to mongodb:

```
Error: Trying to open unclosed connection.
```

Here is my test:

```
var cfg = require('../config')
, mongoose = require('mongoose')
, db = mongoose.connect(cfg.mongo.uri, cfg.mongo.db)
, User = require('../models/user')
, Item = require('../models/item')
, should = require('should')
, fakeUser
, fakeItem;

mongoose.connection.on('error', function(err){
    console.log(err);
});

describe('User', function(){
    beforeEach(function(done){
        //clear out db
        User.remove(done);

    });

    after(function(done){
        //clear out db
        User.remove(function(err){
            Item.remove(done);
        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Close the connection when done:

```
after(function(done){
    //clear out db
    User.remove(function(err){
        Item.remove(function() {
            mongoose.connection.close();
            done();
        });        
    });
});
```

Comment: I think this would normally work, but I have more tests than just this one, so not sure where to put the .after().

Comment: Wrap all tests in a `describe()` that has no tests, only an `after()` block (and the rest of the `describe()` blocks), inside of which you put your `close()` call.